# any standard approach for updating 50 asp.net web applications + database?

Tags: asp.net, database, deployment, updating

I am using VS 2k10 and have a asp.net 4 app with a sql server db behind it, and I have 50 deployments of it (50- databases, 50 web application deployments).

Is there any recommended or standard tool in the industry used for updating mass web applications and databases all at once?

Answer (score 1):

Script it with NAnt... it can pull configs and rewrite the new ones, then deploy all the files.  It can even start and stop IIS.